# Chromium in UWP Apps

Tags: uwp, chromium, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

Hi all,

I know this question(Chromium working on UWP) has been asked before(2015/2016), wanted to see if there is an update on this

I am trying to use the CEF3 build in UWP app and getting the following error in CefInitialize while running the app
CefInitialize(main_args, settings, app.get(), sandbox_info); [settings.multi_threaded_message_loop = false;]

FATAL:platform_channel_pair_win.cc(44)] : Access is denied. (0x5)
[0718/135937.758:FATAL:platform_channel_pair_win.cc(60)] : The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

There are also multiple warnings

Msg:[minkernel\mrt\mrm\src\mrmmin\resourcemap.cpp] 
onecoreuap\base\mrt\runtime\src\cresourceindexinternal.cpp(1479)\MrmCoreR.dll!00007FFE923B3890: (caller: 00007FFE923ACEC7) ReturnHr(252) tid(7a5c) 80073B1F ResourceMap Not Found.

Tried using CEfSharp. Used the OffScreen Nuget package in the UWP app and I am getting build error (The same code works in Console Application)

Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Cannot find type System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost in module System.ServiceModel.dll.

Been stuck on this for long now, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes -
since [October 2020](https://blog.pwabuilder.com/posts/bringing-chromium-edge-pwas-to-the-microsoft-store/) you can package uwp pwa's to run with chromium edge.

The easiest way is to go to https://pwabuilder.com nd build your pwa there.

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/369761/uwp-with-pwa-implementation.html) you can edit the manifest later with VS 2017 (vs0219 pwa uwp templates had been removed).

Though i must say- i was not able to run  a local chromium based pwa via VS2017

best of luck